# Grails 2.3.3 and Solr

Tags: grails, solr, grails-2.3

I am trying to use Grails 2.3.3 with Solr. I have installed the plugin with:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    plugins {
        ...
        compile ":solr:0.2"
    }
}
```

and (the deprecated):

```
$> grails install-plugin solr
```

but it didn't work.  Is this plugin still valid or there are other alternatives for using Solr with Grails 2.3.3?

Comment: I would rather suggest [elastic search plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) instead of searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I think development might be inactive on this plugin. Out of interested I use Searchable very successfully:

BuildConfilg.groovy:

```
plugins { ...
    compile ":searchable:0.6.6"
```

In your domain class:

```
class Article {
   String headline
   String extract

   static searchable = {
      only = ['headline', 'extract']
      headline boost: 2.0, spellCheck: 'include'
      extract boost: 1.7, spellCheck: 'include'
    }
    ...
 }
```

To index in a Service:

```
def searchableService
 ...

     searchableService.index()


}
```

Edit:

The spellcheck add the facility to provide suggested searches if you misspelled the search term:

```
 def suggestedQuery = searchableService.suggestQuery(searchTerm)
```

To search for a term

```
 def searchResult = searchableService.search("dog", options)
```

To match with similar word "cycle" or "cycling" append ~ on to the serach term

```
 def searchResult = searchableService.search("cycle~", options)
```

The options here also allow you to highlight search terms in the result

```
 options.withHighlighter = textHighlighter
```